# How can I compute elements from two different lists in python?

Tags: python, list, variables, object

I have two lists of ints, and I want systematically operate their objects. For example I have:

```
A = [ a1, a2, a3, a4 ...]
B = [ b1, b2, b3 ...]
```

and I want to ***print*** something like this:

```
a1+b1   a2
a2+b2   a3
a3+b3   a4
```

I think there are a "***for*** loop" way, but I don't know how use two variables in a "***for*** loop".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `zip`:

```
>>> A = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
>>> B = ['b1', 'b2', 'b3']
>>> zip(A[:3], B, A[1:])
[('a1', 'b1', 'a2'), ('a2', 'b2', 'a3'), ('a3', 'b3', 'a4')]
>>> for a, b, c in zip(A[:3], B, A[1:]):
...     print a + '+' + b + '   ' + c
... 
a1+b1   a2
a2+b2   a3
a3+b3   a4
```

Comment: @eat, I used strings because they illustrate the transformations more clearly. I'm sure the OP can figure out how to substitute ints.

Comment: As a couple of other posts illustrate, it's not strictly necessary to slice `A` the first time (i.e. `A[:3]`). The list output by `zip` terminates with the shortest input sequence.

Comment: yes, I want to operate ints, but I got it. It works nice. Thanks!

Comment: finally I used:
for a, b, c in zip(A, B, A[1:]):
    print a+b, c
and it's works. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something simple like this:

```
In []: A= [1, 2, 3, 4]
In []: B= [1, 2, 3]
In []: for k, b in enumerate(B):
   ..:     print A[k]+ b, A[k+ 1]
   ..:
2 2
4 3
6 4
```

Or perhaps something like this:

```
In []: for k, b in enumerate(B):
   ..:     print '{}+{}\t{}'.format(A[k], b, A[k+ 1])
   ..:
1+1     2
2+2     3
3+3     4
```

Comment: Looks a very simple solution... I'll try to apply into my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the [`pairwise` recipe from `itertools`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)

a = [1,2,3,4]
b = [7,8,9]

for (a1, a2), b1 in izip(pairwise(a), b):
    print a1 + b1, a2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for i,b in enumerate(B):
    print(A[i] + '+' + b + '\t' + A[i+1])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[(a + b, c) for (a, b, c) in zip(A, B, A[1:])]
```

whatever A and B contain

Answer (score 1):

This one

```
l = zip(map(sum, zip(A, B)), A[1:])
```

would produce a list of tuples of

```
[(a_1 + b_1, a_2), (a_2 + b_2, a_2), ..., (a_(i-1) + b_(i-1), a_i)]
```

To print it,

```
for a, b in l:
    print a, b
```